# Slow Execution - DateAdd and DateDiff in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
... AND (Orders.ShipDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, Datediff(MONTH, 0, GetDate()) -12), 0)
    AND Orders.ShipDate < DATEADD(MONTH, Datediff(MONTH, 0, GetDate()), 0)
```

I was originally using

```
CAST(FLOOR(CAST .....
```

to remove the time component in the where clause with query execution time at 6min - This method relied on a static table so I decided to move away from that. Using the `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` combination, my query is still running 40min later.

This is a known issue in SQL Server 2005 and 2008 according to:
[MSDN Blog Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/07/17/using-datediff-can-query-performance-problems-in-sql-2005-and-2008.aspx)

As this is a view, how do I precompute the `FROM` and `TO` date and pass actual values to reduce the number of passes during query execution?

Comment: On SQL Server **2008**, you could use `CAST(YourColumn AS DATE)` to "remove" the time portion - or use the `DATE` datatype if you don't need time!

Comment: Running SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, Datediff(Day, 0, GetDate() -12), 0) give me a date of '5385-05-01 00:00:00.000'. Maybe this is the issue ?

Comment: The accepted answer in the duplicate has an alternate way of expressing it (or details of a trace flag) that avoids the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're counting the days between "Day 0" and now, but adding that number of MONTHS. You might want to correct that... Otherwise it looks fine enough (just) to me.

Comment: The sample code provided was incorrect but the production code is correct. The issue is that when using datediff and dateadd together, the query slows down to failure

Comment: @MervinPadayachee have you looked at trace flag 4199?

Comment: And if you calculate the values first, it runs at 'normal speed'?

Comment: I would agree to make sure you have traceflag 4199 in use. Test the impact using `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 4199)`